# select MAX(DATE) from Oracle table and pass it to SSIS Variable

Tags: oracle, datetime, ssis

I am trying to get a max date out of a table (and store inside a variable) that I can use in my dataflow task as a starting point for my ETL. But after trying for a lot of time, I am unable to find a solution.

Is there any guide or solution that I can use to solve this? Please let me know if you know the steps. Thank you.

**EDIT**: In the Execute SQL Task, I wrote the following piece of code (with help from online articles):

```
DECLARE 
  FETCH_DATE DATE;
BEGIN
  SELECT MAX(PROCESSED_DT) INTO FETCH_DATE FROM DBO.TABLENAME;
END;
```

The following are the different parameters for my Execute SQL Task:

ResultSet: None (When I tried Single Row, it failed)

Parameter Mapping: The variable which will store the value of the fetched date.Does not work either.

Resultset: As of now, this is blank because when I tried assigning a value to it, it always failed saying could not assign a value.

Connection type is OLEDB.

Oh and BTW, I dont think this is off topic since this is a legitimate programming question. But I will let other experts weigh in. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can't you just execute the SQL: "SELECT MAX(PROCESSED_DT) FROM DBO.TABLENAME" ?

Comment: I tried using that, but it does not work. Not sure why. The error message that Oracle generates is "ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement"

Comment: No I mean without the declare, begin, end part. Just execute a query not a plsql block. some examples here:
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-execute-sql-task-to-generate-result-sets/

Comment: This actually worked for me this time, not sure why I was going head over heels over this. Thank you for your help. If you want to post your comment as an answer, I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the SQL as a query, not as a PLSQL block. Some examples here: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-execute-sql-task-to-generate-result-sets/